# How to write relation operators in GLSL shader code?

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

This is the shader code I am trying to write. I am new to GLSL and needed help regarding this code. I came to know that I cannot use the less than operator(<) in bitwise shader code. I need help with how o write the logic inside if statement (`if(lower[0]<red&&red<upper[0])`) in GLSL shader language?

```c
#version 460

const int w=1280;
const int h=720;

layout(local_size_x=16,local_size_y=16,local_size_z=1)in;

layout(binding=0,std430)buffer _9_2
{
  uint m[w*h];
  
}inBuf;

layout(binding=1,std430)buffer _9_3
{
  uint m[w*h];
}outBuf;

layout(binding=2,std430)buffer _9_4
{
  uint lower[3];
  uint upper[3];
}rgbLimit;

void main()
{
  uint i=gl_WorkGroupID.x*16+gl_LocalInvocationID.x;
  uint j=gl_WorkGroupID.y*16+gl_LocalInvocationID.y;
  uint index=j*w+i;
  
  
  int bayerpixl=int((inBuf.m[index])&255u);
  int red=int((inBuf.m[index]>>24)&0xff);
  int green1=int((inBuf.m[index]>>16)&0xff);
  int green2=int((inBuf.m[index]>>8)&0xff);
  int blue=int((inBuf.m[index])&0xff);
  
  if(lower[0]<red&&red<upper[0])
  {
      int v=255;
  }
  else
  {
      int v=0;
  }
  
  outBuf.m[index]=int(v|(v<<uint(8))|(v<<uint(16)));
  
}
```

I am implementing this code for the image processing in Vulkan.

Comment: Ah okay my bad. But this is C-style coding

Comment: What so you expect from `int v=255;` and `int v=0;`? You declare a variable in the scope of the if and else. These variables are no longer valid afterwards. Declare `int v=0;` before the `if`-statement and set `v=255;` in the code block of the `if`-statement. Or use the ternary conditional operator: `int v = (lower[0]<red&&red<upper[0]) ? 255 : 0;`

Comment: You write `if(lower[0]<red&&red<upper[0])`